# Why is the third parameter of the method decorator in Typescript undefined?

Tags: javascript, typescript

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro.html
why this is undefined?

```
class Person {
  @readonly
  get name() { return `阿斯蒂芬` }
}
function readonly(target, name, descriptor){
  // why descriptor is undefined ???
  descriptor.writable = false; // error

  return descriptor;
}

Person.prototype.name
```

Comment: Do you have a more specific link? This goes to the front matter of the handbook.

Comment: Maybe because you're running in ES5 environment? Property descriptors was opened to developers in ES6 and later versions of Ecmascript.

Comment: it is Typescript, run in ts-node can fix it